# Updating foreign keys in the db or having a model that is maped to db that does not have foreign key (for lazt loading)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

we have many an application that uses a database that is been used by differrent clients (each client has is own DB). Over the years, some of our client's database has lost some of the foreign key definition.

We would like to use code first Entity Framework, but since not all the db has the relationship defined, we have a lot of problems (specialy if we want to use lazy loading).

We where thinking of trying reverse negeneering a db that has the relations defined and to update only the foreign key definitions, is that possible ?

We only want to fix the foreign key definition and nothing else, because there is critical data in the DB and we don't want to take risks and update the db from the model on the production enveironnement.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time following your question mainly because I think you have left a lot of information out. I would think that you could reverse engineer the database, then use automatic-migrations to add any foreign keys. YOu may want to look into:

[Automatic-Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ554735.aspx) AND [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583) or [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)

Without more information or an example of your DB Schema or any Code First (CODE) I don't think anyone will be able to do more than point you in the right direction like I have tried to do.